# Integrate $\int e ^ \sqrt{x} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int e ^ \sqrt{x} \, dx$$

I don't even know how to begin. I tried u sub but obviously doesn't work, no variable to cancel. I tried the formula to memorize $$\int ae^ {au} \, du = \frac{1}{a^2} (au - 1)e^au$$ but that didn't work and I think maybe it isn't suppose to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HINT: Let $u=\sqrt x$; $du=\frac1{2\sqrt x}dx$, so $dx=2\sqrt x du=2u\,du$. Now you have an integral that you can compute by integrating by parts.

Comment: I don't follow where the e vanishes.

Comment: @Paul: It doesn’t vanish. Make the substitution: what is the resulting integral?

Comment: I am having trouble tranforming $1/2 x^{-1/2}$ into what you got. I don't know how to algebraicly manipluate negative fractional exponents.

Comment: @PaulthePirate Exactly how you manipulate positive integer exponents. That's what justifies calling them "exponents".

Comment: @Paul: Use the definition: $x^{-a}=\frac1{x^a}$. Thus, $\frac12x^{-1/2}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{x^{1/2}}=\frac1{2\sqrt x}$.

Comment: Shouldn't I get $\int 2u e^u du$?

Comment: @Paul: Exactly. And that’s a basic integration by parts problem.

Comment: I still get the incorrect answer. I got $\sqrt{x} e^{\sqrt{x}} - e^{\sqrt{x}}$ Nevermind I am an idiot, I forget to multiply by two, this is correct.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

Let $x=t^2$ so $dx=2t \, dt$ and then
$$\int e^{\sqrt{x}} \, dx=2\int te^t \, dt$$
and now integrate by parts.

Answer (score 5):

Let's put $x = y^2,\;\;\sqrt x = y.\;\;$ Then $\,dx = 2y\,dy$.

Substituting, this gives us:

$$\int e^{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\int ye^ydy$$

which lends itself nicely to integration by parts.

$$\begin{align} 2\int ye^y\,dy & = 2\left( ye^y - \int e^y\,dy\right) \\ \\
& = 2\left(ye^y - e^y\right) + C \\ \\ 
& = 2e^y\left(y - 1)\right) + C \\ \\ 
& = 2e^{\sqrt x}\left(\sqrt x - 1\right) + C \end{align}$$